# Access to the dex task after 1.5.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Starting with 1.5.0 the The Dex class is gone. I want to migrate to the Gradle plugin 2.2.2 but I need to run some task after the dex file is built and before APK is created.

Is there a way to use new Transfrom API to access the DexTransform output?